# Debuging to simulator crashes with "exited with status 5" unless I have breakpoint

Tags: iphone

For some reason the app I am working on has very bad PMT! Literally! Most of the time I cannot debug using the simulator without putting a breakpoint in my AppDelegate. If I don't it exists with "status 5". If I put a break point in and simple continue it works perfectly well, it also works if I run the app in the simulator when not connected to the GDB.

I have tried the source on a second machine with exactly the same results. I dont have this issue building to the device?!?!?!

Thanks

Comment: Hi, where in your app delegate do you have to put a breakpoint; can you post some code?

Comment: I doesnt matter, in fact I just need to have breakpoints enabled!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from : http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/100/topics/2168

```
Sep 14, 2010 9:55am

Mark Allen
(1 post)
I had this too. Fortunately I had the project under source control, so I did
a diff and realised the project file is not the culprit. Turns out there is no
need to create new projects or anything. Just delete your personal settings files
for the project. They will be username.mode1v3 and username.pbxuser. I didn’t 
figure out which file was the cause, but deleting them sorted it out.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Restarting X-Code didn't help.

What did help was clearing all my breakpoints.

From the X-Code menu, click Run -> Show -> Breakpoints, then, from the breakpoints screen delete all breakpoints. Shut down the simulator, then rebuild the project.

Problem solved for me.

Comment: Problem went away, but then returned. Now works by having breakpoint enabled, without having any active breakpoints. From reading round on the net seems to be config file corruption of sorts. In my readings someone said "problems that go away by themselves can also come back by themselves". Hope this one stays away.

Comment: Problem kept on re-occuring. Had spent many hours trying to overcome this, without any success. Eventually though, **it was resolved by upgrading from XCode 3.?? to XCode 4**. XCode 4 solved the problem.