# Xcode Exit codes and signals

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, exit-code

I've looked around and never found a comprehensive list of exit codes for Xcode especially working with iOS. This question: [Debuging to simulator crashes with "exited with status 5" unless I have breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504512/debuging-to-simulator-crashes-with-exited-with-status-5-unless-i-have-breakpoin) simply says I need to restart xcode to solve a common problem labeled 'exit code 5'. There are many other similar questions out there. The solutions often work, however I don't understand how they work. Next time I come across once of these exit code's I'd like to know what they mean so I can have a better idea of how to prevent it from happening again.

What are the common Xcode signals and exit codes?

Comment: A duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504512/debuging-to-simulator-crashes-with-exited-with-status-5-unless-i-have-breakpoin

Comment: I'm going to reword the question to simply ask for a list of signals if thats okay. Now there is no need to mention my particular problem... Also in my defense there still is no accepted answer for this 'Duplicated question' as I mentioned that didn't work so I wanted to solve my problem by getting what exit code 5 meant.

Comment: You should further detail the original question, not open a new one just to ask people for an answer. Just give people time to read, find and appropriately answer

Comment: Okay I've reworded the question I hope people find it much clearer, I don't think the question is really about Exit Code 5 nearly so much as what are the signals. With this change I'll also accept Grady's Answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

signal 0 an 1 are pretty standard, others are defined in context and by users, on osx 10.6:

man signal gives:

```
 2     SIGINT       terminate process    interrupt program
 3     SIGQUIT      create core image    quit program
 4     SIGILL       create core image    illegal instruction
 5     SIGTRAP      create core image    trace trap
 6     SIGABRT      create core image    abort program (formerly SIGIOT)
 7     SIGEMT       create core image    emulate instruction executed
 8     SIGFPE       create core image    floating-point exception
 9     SIGKILL      terminate process    kill program
 10    SIGBUS       create core image    bus error
 11    SIGSEGV      create core image    segmentation violation
 12    SIGSYS       create core image    non-existent system call invoked
 13    SIGPIPE      terminate process    write on a pipe with no reader
 14    SIGALRM      terminate process    real-time timer expired
 15    SIGTERM      terminate process    software termination signal
 16    SIGURG       discard signal       urgent condition present on
                                         socket
 17    SIGSTOP      stop process         stop (cannot be caught or
                                         ignored)
 18    SIGTSTP      stop process         stop signal generated from
                                         keyboard
 19    SIGCONT      discard signal       continue after stop
 20    SIGCHLD      discard signal       child status has changed
 21    SIGTTIN      stop process         background read attempted from
                                         control terminal
 22    SIGTTOU      stop process         background write attempted to
                                         control terminal
 23    SIGIO        discard signal       I/O is possible on a descriptor
                                         (see fcntl(2))
 24    SIGXCPU      terminate process    cpu time limit exceeded (see
                                         setrlimit(2))
 25    SIGXFSZ      terminate process    file size limit exceeded (see
                                         setrlimit(2))
 26    SIGVTALRM    terminate process    virtual time alarm (see
                                         setitimer(2))
 27    SIGPROF      terminate process    profiling timer alarm (see
                                         setitimer(2))
 28    SIGWINCH     discard signal       Window size change
 29    SIGINFO      discard signal       status request from keyboard
 30    SIGUSR1      terminate process    User defined signal 1
 31    SIGUSR2      terminate process    User defined signal 2
```

Comment: true, but if an application is killed with a signal, they can use that as the exit code, dont know if xcode does, but i have done it.

Comment: SIGTRAP doesn't kill a process.

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Comment: that would also explain why the debugger being enabled would make it not crash.

Comment: Uh, what? That's not an exit code. That's an exception. The process doesn't even get a chance to emit an exit code in that case.

Comment: it would if it registered the signal... xcode 3 works differently from xcode 4 in that respect. xcode 3 just quits.

Comment: If it registered a signal handler and caught SIGTRAP, then it could return any code it wanted, not just 5.

Comment: absolutely, my point is that because xcode is closed source and the exit codes are only meaningful to the developers of xcode, and not published, it is possible that it is the signal number.

Comment: well i am wrong anyway it exits with 143 for -5, and the others look to be in the 130's

Comment: So signals or exit codes should I rephrase the question for clarity? I certainly didn't know the difference when I wrote the question.

Comment: no you are correct, exit codes are what are passed from the exit() function when a program exits, signals are messages sent to the program generally by the kernel or the kill command.