# What does exit code 4 indicate on Xcode?

Tags: c++, debugging

I made a simple program which I was trying to crash. Code is as follow:

```
void Race4(){
 int * p = nullptr;
 *p = 50;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 Race4();
 return 0;
}
```

When I run it on Xcode, I get output as:
`Program ended with exit code: 4`

When I run the same program via terminal, I get

```
➜ Release ./Debuging_Profiling
[1]  65903 illegal hardware instruction ./Debuging_Profiling
```

My original aim was to get a crash and use `atos` tool to get symbols from addresses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740981/xcode-exit-codes-and-signals it says 4 is "illegal instruction".

Comment: `Race4()` invokes undefined behavior. This means anything can happen: crash, nothing, strange behavior, or demons can fly out of your nose. You got crash as. desired. You are asking wrong question or didn't provide all details. I see "release" build. What do you expect Xcode should do? Why you thing running in console give different exit code?

Comment: Thanks @pptaszni & Marek R . I love your definition of UB, I'll be using that. 
I was expecting it to crash and give like a crash stack or when Xcode stopping on troublesome line when attached

Comment: It is not my definition of UB (google it).

Comment: "crash stack" - you mean like a backtrace from debugger `#1 0x123 in foo() at src.cpp: 66` ? You don't need to crash your application (it's actually not guaranteed to crash if you cause UB) for that, use debugger breakpoints, throw exception, call `std::abort`, etc ...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the disassembly of `Race4`? I bet clang is outputting a `ud2` instruction or whatever the ARM equivalent is.